# how to select specific columns in mysql without enumerating the column names

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select specific columns in MySQL without enumerating the column names?

I would like to get the data from the 3rd column until the 10th column without using this kind of query -> **select 3rd_column, ..., 10th_column from table;**

Imagine how hard it is if there are 100 columns and i like to get the data in the last 80 columns.

Thank you.

Comment: you can read the name from information_schema like.TABLES

Comment: "*if there are 100 columns and i like to get the data in the last 80 columns*", you should redesign your database!  A table with 100 columns is almost certainly ***terrible*** design.  And to rely on column position tightly couples  your application with the schema version—what happens if columns are added/removed/reordered?  Your application would have to be rewritten!

Comment: haha. I know right? that's what i'm trying to fix. Thank you.

Comment: I've looked at the Is there a way to select nth column in a SELECT clause from a table/view. Yes i think they're similar in question except that i'm looking specifically for MySQL and I can't find the answer in that thread. I guess, there's really no way to do this currently. Well, thank you for the response. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT  TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'sakila' AND ORDINAL_POSITION > 2
```

Comment: once you have this info you can build a sql statement